# Optimizing multiple selects from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to optimize the query that is consumed by a report. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the report, so I have to provide a specificly formatted dataset.

So, let's say I have a table that looks like this(In practice, it has 25 columns and 20k rows):

```
Name    Description           Price     MiscColumn1    MiscColumn2    
Tea      test description      10       misc1            misc2   
Coffee    test desc            20       misc3            misc4
Water      test                20       misc1            misc2
```

So, I need to  transform this dataset to look like this:

```
Type  Name    Description           Price     MiscColumn1    MiscColumn2 
  1    Tea     test description      NULL       NULL           NULL  
  1    Coffee   test desc            NULL       NULL           NULL 
  1    Water     test                NULL       NULL           NULL
  2    NULL      NULL                 10        NULL           NULL
  2    NULL      NULL                 20        NULL           NULL  
  3    NULL      NULL                NULL       misc1          misc2
  3    NULL      NULL                NULL       misc3          misc4
```

So, basically what I need to do is to select 3 groups of distinct records back into the dataset.

What I currently do is:

```
Create #tempTable
```

And then do a 3 separate distinct selects like this:

```
insert into #tempTable (Name, Description)  
select distinct Name, DEscription from myTable  
 insert into #tempTable (Price)  
select distinct Price from myTable
```

But it is really slow and can take up to 5 seconds to complete with my data.

Also, I was trying to use UNION, but I didn't gain any performance improvement.

Comment: `union all` is better than `union` if you know beforehand that all the rows from two sets are different - here they are by virtue of _type_. But to gain speed you should consider creating composite indexes on groups of columns you select separately.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, I cannot use union all, because of the duplicates in subsets. Can you please show me a simple example of correct indexes for my sample above? The first table with 3 rows is a temp table. I'm not sure if Indexes will help though.

Comment: You could still use `union all` over `select distinct` as it will avoid `distinct sort` operation, but I doubt that this will help a lot. I didn't understand that base table is also temporary. If it was not I'd try with indexes on (Name, Description), (Price) and (MiscColumn1, MiscColumn2). With temporary table this could even slow query down. Could you change the process of populating first table to get the right format in first step?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, what I have in the first step is a statement that looks like this: select <column_list> into #myTemp from table1 left join table2 left join table3....(15 tables). And I'm not sure how to do this in one query. Use PIVOT perhaps? Cannot wrap my head around it though.

Comment: ErikE's answer seems promising. You can get rid of temporary table by substituting your query for `dbo.MyTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single statement, which should involve a single scan, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   X.*
FROM
   dbo.MyTable T
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (1, T.Name, T.Description, NULL, NULL, NULL),
      (2, NULL, NULL, T.Price, NULL, NULL),
      (3, NULL, NULL, NULL, T.MiscColumn1, T.MiscColumn2)
   ) X (Type, Name, Description, Price, MiscColumn1, MiscColumn2)
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cfcf/1)

Note that you don't need a temporary table--you can do your 15 joins and then in the `CROSS APPLY` simply refer to the table that each column comes from.

That brings up a point. Your data is coming from 15 tables! If any of the `Type` groupings of values come from a distinct subset of tables, then this is probably not the best way to do it! Let's say, for example, that `MiscColumn1` and `MiscColumn2` come from 2 tables that have no columns represented in another group. In that case, it will be much better to remove those 2 tables from the main query, and `UNION ALL SELECT` just the 2 columns from those tables separately.

I'm saying this based on the possibly mistaken impression I am getting that your reporting platform is going to do its own joining of various related data. If so, then you shouldn't try to put together the unified view of all the data, then break it back down again--that is putting extra work on the system for no reason. The need for the `DISTINCT` in the above query highlights the extra memory, I/O, and CPU that will be required to materialize the trimmed-down result set you need. If there's any way to get around that, I think you should do it.

Comment: +1, never thought of **cross apply** as _unpivoting_ tool :-)

Comment: Thank you for providing a nice trick with cross apply. all of the 15tables are joined to each other. I think you're correct about subsets of data. We just need to denormalize some of our tables.Unfortunately, at this point CROSS APPLY solution runs 1.5-2x slower than Union temp table on my database. Not sure what can be the cause of it though. Do you know of other ways of aggregating data?

Comment: @user194076 The speed difference is probably due to the server ignoring certain tables in the join for each different `SELECT`--tables that have no columns selected in a query may be excluded. Which, ironically, is what I said needed to happen to be the gain the best result. If I were the one troubleshooting your query, I would start examining the execution plan, data types, join conditions, and indexes. It is unfortunate that helping you at this point is probably too complicated for a reasonable stackoverflow question...

Comment: @user194076 Oh, also, do you find any difference by still using the temp table, but with my query?